# standalone-full.xml errors - unrecognised jboss properties

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I am seeing several errors in my **standalone-full.xml** in a maven project in eclipse. The following line (one of many) has errors displayed.

```
<socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
```

Error:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - cvc-attribute.3: The value '${jboss.management.http.port:9990}' of attribute 'port' on element 'socket-binding' is not valid with respect
>   to its     type, 'unsignedShort'.
>     - cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '${jboss.management.http.port:9990}' is not a valid value for 'integer'.

I realize this is because the jboss properties are not being picked up. However "jboss.home" is recognized.

Has anyone seen this before? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today in multiple lines in a `standalone.xml` and I changed all the `socket-bindings` like this:

```
<socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="9990"/>
```

After this the errors were gone. I'm not sure what caused the problem but it seems it depends on which version of JBoss you are using. According to the link below they may change the configuration from build to build.

[Here I found the solution](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-77592)